# Add a blank line in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem in datatable when adding a new line:

I want to add a blank line, but if I click on the button it adds a line but component remains.

`<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` contains old value.

That is to say value of `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` preserves the value of the previous line

---

```
<p:dataTable value="#{solotionManager.customers}"
             id="table" var="o"
             widgetVar="50"
             style="width: 100%;"
             editable="true"
             scrollHeight="330"
             styleClass="datatable">

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{customerBeansController2.onEdit}" update=":form1:table" process="@this"/>

    <f:facet name="header">
        Order List
    </f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{customerBeansController2.onCancel}" update=":form1:messages"/>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <h:outputText value="ID customer"  style="width:100%"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{o.id}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{o.id}" style="width:100%"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="firstName"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{o.firstName}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{o.firstName}" style="width:100%"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="lastName"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{o.lastName}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{o.lastName}" style="width:100%"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="SelectManyMenu" style="width:100%"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{solotionManager.choice}" label="Phone" converter="entrantConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{solotionManager.listeChoice}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu >
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{solotionManager.choice}" label="Phone" converter="entrantConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{solotionManager.listeChoice}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c}"/>
                </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Options">
        <p:rowEditor/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public String newLine(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    this.customers.add(this.custom1);
    this.custom1=new Customer();
    return null;    
}
```

the code for the button that adds the line:

---

```
<p:commandButton value="add row"  actionListener="#{solotionManager.newLine}"     update="table" oncomplete="addRowOnComplete()"/>
```

Function javascript addRowOncomplete :

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRowOnComplete() {
       jQuery('.ui-datatable-data tr td').last().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){jQuery(this).click();});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the button that adds the line?

Comment: the code for the button that adds the line :

Comment: First of all, an `actionListener` should have a return type of `void`. What's the scope of your backing bean?